# SPSS: aggregate and count different values

Tags: spss

In SPSS i have a variabele with a lot of different values (8 figure number; 00000000). Every row is a person. I want to aggregate this data on postal area and count the number of different values in a postal area.  Is there a way?

Result within a postal area should be 1 to N : 1 = every person has the same value, N = every person has a different value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aggregate in two steps. Assuming your dataset name is `data1`, with variables `var1` (the variable of interest) and `postalcode`, I would do this:

Create a dataset `step1`, with one row for each combination of values of `postalcode` and `var1`. Also possible by using the command `casestovars`.

```
dataset declare step1.
dataset activate data1.
aggregate outf=step1 /break=postalcode var1 /n=n(var1).
```

Create a dataset `result` with one row for each postalcode, and a variable `n` for the number of rows from the previous dataset `step1`.

```
dataset declare result.
dataset activate step1.
aggregate outf=result /break=postalcode /n=n(var1).
```

So, in conclusion: first break by both of the variables, then break only by the variable of postal code. This should do the trick!